# Regional webhook fulfillment for Google Assistant apps via Dialogflow

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Now that [localization is available](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/) for Actions on Google, I'm wondering about minimizing latency for user responses. In a stack where an app is using Dialogflow for NLP and then a Google Cloud Function behind that for webhook fulfillment, is it possible to set up cloud functions where a specific localized experience has been established in Actions on Google? In other words, can we set up English-US responses to be provided by a cloud function hosted in us-central1, and English-GB via europe-west1 Google datacenters?

With Alexa & ASK you can set up a language with 'geographical region endpoints' in N America, Europe and India and have Lambda functions fulfill intents from users in those regions.

Dialogflow may not be available in multiple GCP regions, but if it is it would be nice to keep fulfillment local with google cloud functions close to where the user is - if it minimizes conversation delays. Maybe someone has data to suggest it doesn't matter and is fast enough either way.

Comment: Have you experience high latency with Dialogflow?

Comment: @matthewayne No, but I haven't tested from Europe or other international locations.

Comment: I don't this is possible at this time.

Comment: @matthewayne Yes, I've experienced latencies up to 1.2 seconds (1200ms!) because the round-trip to Mountain View from Europe. I'm working on a google assistant agent in the Netherlands. The average (round-trip) latency for us seems to be somewhere between 500 and 700ms, which is still much too high.